# how to pass a javascript variable in a url

Tags: javascript, html, url

I am trying pass the fileName variable in the url and it does not seem to be working. I have checked related questions and I am pretty convinced that I am doing the right thing. I even tried logging the values of the variables to the console and its working but when I navigate to play_offline.php, the variable is not being carried by the url. Please guide me, where am i going wrong?

```
var list_item = $('<a href="play_offline.php?li="' + filename + '><li id="videos">' + ' ' + cursor.key + ' ' + '</li></a>');
```

Comment: you should include a code instead of a image.

Comment: Please avoid links and add your code here

Comment: @CarlBinalla, by navigating, i mean by clicking the link. I appended list_item

Comment: The `href` has a missing quote `"` at the end of `filename+'`

Comment: You need to check the quotes; move the `href`'s closing `"` over to after `filename`.

Comment: Here's my take: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/1p28L7ch/

Comment: @ChrisG thanks a lot, your suggestion worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are ending the `href` with `"` before append the `filename`.

**Simply Use Javascript Template String**

```
var listitem = `<a href='play_offline.php?li=${fileName}'><li id='videos'>${cursor.key}</li></a>`;
```